# Django with Docker is not allowing to access external API and is throwing Failed to resolve 'my-host-name' ([Errno -5] No address associated

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, django-views

I am new to django and Docker. The issue I am facing is when I want to fetch some data from external API and just display it in a view I am getting an error  "Failed to resolve 'my-host-name' ([Errno -5] No address associated with hostname". But the API is working fine in postman and I tested it

Here is my view file:

```
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests



def index(request):
    host='http://my_host:8190'
    token='My_Auth_Token'
    hd = {'Authorization': str({token})}
    
    data=requests.get(f"{host}/api/xyz" ,headers=hd)
    return render(request,"Loading/index.html",{'bundles':data})
```

In the html file  I am just displaying the data.

Please help me out with this.

Thanks in advance

:)

I am trying to access an API endpoint for which I am getting  Failed to resolve 'srd-web-apps-dev' ([Errno -5] No address associated with hostname when I use djang`your text`o with docker. But If I use django without Docker it doesn't throw any error.

Answer (score 1):

Probably issue comes from DNS.
Can you try running the nslookup command with a DNS server specified? Like:

docker run busybox nslookup google.com 8.8.8.8

See the results and check if another DNS works for you. If problem wasn't about your dns check other connection settings like if you use proxy or other connection settings.
You can also check other external domains to see if problem comes from dns.